# Upgrading fails from 12.10 to 13.04 (Check Internet Settings)

Tags: 12.10, 13.04

I am unable to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04. It fails with the error message:

```
check your internet settings
```

My internet is working and I am able to browse the Internet, see emails, etc.

Comment: Try turning off local firewall using below command.                                                                                                    services ufw stop

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system, login, and open a terminal and do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: tried the above suggestion; i get "Failed to fetch http://suro.ubaya.ac.id/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Unable to connect to suro.ubaya.ac.Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Please paste the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, along with the results for `ls -lhaR /etc/apt/` in your question.

Comment: unable to post it here since it is too long; can i send it by email?

Comment: No, just use the Ubuntu Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: i did it just now

Comment: Ok, now give us the link to your paste.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5669721/.

Comment: just added the paste link above. let me know how to solve this issue?